# BigQuery: project does not have the reservation in the data region

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a project that is configured to use EU slots only. Using the BigQuery UI I can specify the region and run queries successfully.

However when I use the JAVA API I keep getting "project does not have the reservation in the data region"

I have tried to use  .setLocation("eu") in QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder but no luck there. Same error.

Does anyone know how can I make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation on dataset regions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-locations#regional_locations), valid values (at the time of this writing) are `US`, `EU`, and `asia-northeast1`. The `EU` value needs to be in uppercase.